# How to differentiate two mice in a computer?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, hook, driver

Well, I want to share a desktop environment with many user, so it seems to need input isolation. First of all, how to How to differentiate two mice in a computer? Then I can draw cursor and deal with their events seperately. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [Windows MultiPoint Mouse Software Development Kit 1.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9962)

> Windows MultiPoint Mouse Software Development Kit (SDK) is a
>   development framework that allows developers to build applications
>   that enable multiple individual mouse devices to work simultaneously
>   on one computer.

Comment: Thanks, it seems a good native solution. And how about two keyboards?

Comment: Well, I found a good solution too. Using "Raw input" to get the device information.